# large space in dashboard of Magento 2.1.9

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, admin, store-view, dashboard

I'm using Magento 2.1.9. I don't know why the view of pages in dashboards as in the image. I must go down to see the content of the page and there is large space at the beginning of the page. 
any help, please? 
[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

also, store view not appear on a product page in admin panel. 
I have two store view. I need a solution quickly please, is there any help?
[image: store view]

Comment: Neither we. check styles, markup and so on or provide us with some data to evaluate.

Comment: @BartoszHerba what data you need to provide? all pages as this page

Comment: @BartoszHerba how to check styles and markup?